# ¿Como puedo hacer que el form mantenga inalterable su tamaño en pixels al cambiar de resolución?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, ui

Tengo una aplicación basada en un enfoque de interfaz vectorial, en la que no quiero usar XAML, ni esta presente.

Imicialmente el Form1, de la aplicación, tiene un tamaño, en el que el alto es de 975 pixels.

Estoy desarrollando una clase para que se ocupe de adecuar el tamaño del Form.

Al cambiar la resolución, quisiera que el tamaño del Form, no cambiase. Se mantuviera con su ancho y alto originales, y asi la clase se encargue de redimensionarlo adecuadamente.

He probado poner Autoescalado Off, pero igual reduce de forma que no conecta matematicamente con las resoluciones ni el factor de escalado original del form, ni eventual de inicio de la aplicación.

Para desarrollar en modo vectorial, uso una plantilla para que el IDE active el modo vectorial, y permita asi el desarrollo y funciomamiento gráfico de las ventanas de la aplicación, también agrego las referencias, Presentation.FrameWork y Windows.Base.

Plantilla de código para encapsular app como aplicacion Windows Presentation Fundation.

```
public partial class Form1:Form
{
public class App:System.Windows.Application
Form1 appForm1;
  
   public void App_ini(Form1 _appForm1)
   {
   appForm1 = _appForm1;
   return;
   }
}
```

...

He agregado la referencia Presentation.Core para ver si genera cambios en el comportamiento grafico de la ventana de la app.

He observado que, ahora ya no altera tanto el tamaño.

La resolucion en que desarrollo la app ejemplo, es 1920x1080 x150% de escalado.

He reducido el alto de la ventana a 840, por probar otro ejemplo

Al iniciar en una resolucion distinta a la de desarrollo, menor,deja el alto de la ventana en 823, mientras que espería que lo deje en 840.

Gracias.

Comment: Y tenes un [MCVE] para proporcionar? porque lo que preguntas, ademas de complejo, es muy particular...

Answer (score 0):

Al cambiar de referencia para trabajar en vectorial, agregando Presetation.Core, el tamaño de la ventana sin tocar aun por la clase al efecto, la deja casi igual, esto debe ser, porque en una resolución menor, tiene un alto bastante mayor que el alto de la pantalla y causa que igual lo reduzca un poco, alterando su tamaño original.

Sin embargo, al procesarlo con la clase al efecto ya cuadra correctamente con el resultado de equivalencia al tamaño original de la ventana, por lo que ya si se puede redimensionar la ventana en base a los parametros de definicion y escalado.

Asi que lo que he hecho para corregir esas alteraciones mayores (que truncaban mal a poco mas de 2/3 la ventana..), ha sido añadir la referencia Presentation.Core.